# PHP Paypal REST create payment malfromed JSON response

Tags: php, json, rest, paypal

Sorry about this (last resort, short of shooting myself in the head ;-); it's obviously my fault somewhere but I've spent days searching here and elsewhere, reading docs, trying various things etc. But it still won't work.

Some one please point me what's wrong here:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    "intent" => "sale",
    "redirect_urls" => array(
            "return_url" => "http://.../ok.html",
            "cancel_url" => "http://.../cancel.html"
        ),
    "payer" => array(
            "payment_method" => "paypal"
        ),
    "transactions" => array(
            "amount" => array(
                    "total" => "1.23",
                    "currency" => "GBP"
                )
        )
);

$ch = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$logfile = fopen("curl_log.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $logfile);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Bearer <long token returned from REST call',
  ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($logfile);

?>
```

Error:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"developer.paypal.com/webapps/de‌​veloper/docs/api/…;}
```

Comment: What's the error message or the curl result ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Is there any error ? Please explain your question.

Comment: Use [curl error function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-strerror.php) to get actual error details

Comment: Sorry; it's:{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"f7dc403399f4d"}

Comment: I'm simply (I thought) trying to 'create a payment'; getting the token was a doddle. Create payment is the next step.

Comment: are you facing same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your $data array like,

```
$data = array(
    "intent" => "sale",
    "payer" => array(
            "payment_method" => "paypal"
        ),
    "transactions" =>array( 
            array(
                "amount" => array(
                        "total" => "1.23",
                        "currency" => "GBP")
            )
        ),
    "redirect_urls" => array(
            "return_url" => "http://.../ok.html",
            "cancel_url" => "http://.../cancel.html"
     )
);
```

Comment: it is not copy paste, you need to wrap transaction array in one more array

Comment: if it worked, then upvote the answer, so it will be helpfull for others too

Comment: It does work. My upvotes don't count for much I'm afraid but I've done what I can. The [array][array][array][array] depth of 'transactions' seems to be a common problem and there are several incorrect answers on here and elsewhere. Thanks again.